# How to undo after patch is applied? .rej/.orig files

Tags: diff, patch

The case is following. I have two files: `file1.c`, `file2.c`

```
ls 
file1.c file2.c patch.diff
patch < patch.diff
...
x out of x hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file file1.c.rej 
(the same with file2.c)
ls
file1.c file2.c file1.c.orig file2.c.orig file1.c.rej file2.c.rej patch.diff
patch -R < patch.diff # I thought it will revert changes back
...
x out of x hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file file1.c.rej
(again, the same with file2.c)    
ls
file1.c file2.c file1.c.orig file2.c.orig file1.c.rej file2.c.rej patch.diff
```

Now I left with broken files and have no idea how to get them back. It seems that the *.orig files were replaced on second pass with already broken changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your two `x out of x hunk FAILED` messages the same? Are the values of `x` the same? It would help if you could put proper messages here - it doesn't affect your security.

Comment: Unfortunately, the messages are lost. Deadend..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking this question here, but since the question is about software development, you'll likely get much better answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always a good idea to make backup copies from the original files.

This can be done automatically if you call `patch` with option `-b`.

Background: in case that there is no `.rej` file, you could call:

```
patch -R
```

to reverse the patch, but this does not work in case of a problem.

Note that in case that `file2.c.orig` already exists when `patch` starts, this file is removed and replaced by a backup copy of the current state.

If you have these `.orig` files, you could easily rename them to the original filename in order to undo the patch.

Note that it may be a good idea to reverse all patches to all files in a project in case that a single patch fails. Since this requires `.orig` files for all patched files, it is recommended to use

```
patch -b
```

If you have these `.orig` files, you could call:

```
for i in *.orig; do
    base=`basename $i .orig`
    mv $i $base
done
```

Comment: Does it backup (with `-b` flag) even if the same filename already exists?

Comment: What do you understand by "the same filename"?

Comment: I've read your post update. Thank you. But what's the point? If the patch is failed it already create `.orig` file which is kind of backup, isn't it?

Comment: It is not granted behavior that `patch` created a .orig file in case of a failure. BTW: .bak was a typo